# Htaccess 301 redirection

Tags: .htaccess

Can any one please help me on the htaccess 301 redirection

when i use the following URL `www.sb.my-sitename.co.uk` in the address bar of the browser and which has to be redirected to

```
https://sb.my-sitename.co.uk
```

Here i need to remove the `www` part and include `https://` in front of the URL since `sb.` is the sub-domain

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Redirect 301 / https://sb.my-sitename.co.uk
```

Put that in a `.htaccess` of the root of your `www.sb.my-sitename.co.uk` site folder.

To remove the `www`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Replace `example.com` with your URL