# htaccess redirects for subdomain and all links

Tags: php, .htaccess

Does anyone know of any 301 .htaccess rules than would cover all links on a website. Here's a few examples:

Examples:

```
https://support.olddomain.com/
https://support.newdomain.com/

https://support.olddomain.com/id.php?pp=sdf-sdf-sdf&r=13
https://support.newdomain.com/id.php?pp=sdf-sdf-sdf&r=13
```

Comment: You will find literally hundreds of working solutions here on SO if you look for it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Htaccess 301 redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5232556/htaccess-301-redirection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two hostnames (ie. `support.olddomain.com` and `support.newdomain.com`) point to different servers then you can use a simple mod_alias `Redirect` in the `.htaccess` file at the old-domain. For example:

```
# Redirect everything to the new-domain (like for like URLs)
Redirect 301 / https://support.newdomain.com/
```

However, if the two hostnames point to the same place then you need to use mod_rewrite and explicitly check the requested hostname in order to avoid a redirect loop. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect everything to the new-domain (like for like URLs)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =support.olddomain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://support.newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Both sets of rules do the same thing... ie. 301 redirect `https://support.newdomain.com/<url-path>?<query-string>` to the same `<url-path>` and `<query-string>` at `https://support.newdomain.com/`.